# Cannot filter categories by parent category

Tags: categories

I'm trying to get all direct child categories in category hierarchy.

What I've tried:

```
$args = array(
        'child_of' => get_query_var("cat")
        );
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $catID = $category->cat_ID;
    $test = "cat_ID: " . $category->cat_ID . " " . "parent: " . $category->parent . ", "; 
    echo $test;
}
```

In case`get_query_var("cat") == 14` I get the following result:

> cat_ID: 35 parent: 14, cat_ID: 34 parent: 14, cat_ID: 36 parent: 34, cat_ID: 37 parent: 34,

which is not what I want because this displays child's child categories. So I tried

```
$args = array(
        'parent' => strval(get_query_var("cat"))
        );
```

which results in

> cat_ID: 35 parent: 14,

instead of what I expected

> cat_ID: 35 parent: 14, cat_ID: 34 parent: 14,

So what's going wrong?

Comment: `parent` only fetch the direct descendant of the parent category ID Are you child category at same level?

Comment: I think so. please see the first result using 'child_of' => get_query_var("cat") as filter where there are two results with 14 as parent

Comment: What is your category structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get direct descendants (i.e. children only) of the category, you need to make use of the `parent` parameter in [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

The reason why you might not see your other category is that it does not have any posts assigned to it. To display empty categories, you need to set the `hide_empty` parameter to `0`

Otherwise I do not see any problems with your code. You should also turn on debugging to check if you maybe have some kind of error if the above does not work

Comment: hide_empty brought the solution! I'm still confused why hide_empty has an effect on the 'parent' but not on the 'child_of' filter...